# Orthogonality of Level Sets of Certain Functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

My question reads:

At what points in the plane are the level sets of the following functions orthogonal?

$$
\begin{align*}
f(x,y) &= x^2 + y^2 - 2xy  \\
g(x,y) &= 2y - 3x
\end{align*}
$$

Initially, my thought is to set $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ equal to some constants, $c$ and $d$. From there, I'm unsure of where to go.

What should be my next steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that a level set $f(x,y)=c$ consists of a pair of lines $x-y = \sqrt{c}$ and $x-y=-\sqrt{c}$, if $c>0$. The level sets $g(x,y)=d$ are lines $2y-3x=d$. These lines intersect nowhere orthogonally (since the product of their slopes is not $-1$).